# Get the file path to read dynamically from user in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, filereader

After doing some research, i found a way to read files in php using the following codE:

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Now i want to get the  filename(path) through the pop up window which enables user to select the file from his/her file explorer. How to do that behind the html button:

```
<input  type="file" id="loadFile"/>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he is trying to read a file uploaded by a user through and html form?

Comment: Then he is getting the wrong idea about uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but I think this answers your question:

After the user has selected a file, they need to upload (POST) it to the server (but submitting the form). For a simple, but good, tutorial on this, check out http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

After the file has been received and saved server-side you can read it with the code you have, or the simpler:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
```

You should be very careful accepting uploads from users and should make sure that you make sure you accept only files you are expecting so you could get your server compromised.